# One ScaleTransform to a group of layers

Tags: c#, wpf, layouttransform

Here's what I want to do - given a couple of [image] layers inside a scrollviewer, I'd like to apply the same scaling factor to all layers.

In Xaml, I have a scroll viewer that hosts a grid that hosts two image controls. I have a checkbox that controls the visibility of the top image. Right now, I have a scaletransform for each image, and apply the same scale for both.

Is there a way to unify scaling in just one container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can just apply the scale transform at a higher level, e.g. you could apply it to the grid.

```
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
      <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
      </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
```

That will automatically propagate the transform down to any child that ends up inside that grid.

Regards,
Donovan